# I cant add property to the array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Hello this is my first time using javascript. I want to ask something. Why I cant add the value to array of object? I want to add some validation. this is my code.

```
let user = [];

function register(username, password) {

    this.id = user.length + 1;
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
}

function addUser(username, password) {
    for(var i=0; i< user.length; i++){
        if(user[i].username != username){
            user.push(new register(username, password))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have no users, how would your for loop conditional ever be true?

Comment: Not only can you not add another user when you have no users, but if you _did_ have users then you'd be adding the new user multiple times for every current user that _isn't_ the new user. You need to rethink that logic.

Comment: `var userExists = users.find(it => it.username == username); if (!userExists) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate that the username is not in use, i would do something like this:

```
function addUser(username, password) {
    var used = false;
    for(var i=0; i< user.length; i++){
        if(user[i].username === username){
            used = true;
        }
    }

    if (!used) {user.push(new register(username, password));}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @taplar mainioned, You can use `array.find` method with a `callback` to get user. If not use add/push to add user.

```
let users = [];

function register(username, password) {
  this.id = users.length + 1;
  this.username = username;
  this.password = password;
}

function addUser(username, password) {
  const user = users.find(user => user.username != username)
  if(!user) users.push(new register(username, password))
}
```